# Set static variable from config's file in PHP

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP-static-class that writes in log.txt the log of my script.
It is:

```
<?php

class Log {

    $fileLogConfig = ''; //include 'config.inc'; -> it's an error!

    //Write the log in log.txt
    public static function tracciaOperazioniNelLog($operation) {
        $fileLog = fopen($fileLogConfig['log'], "a+") or die("Error! \n");
        fwrite($fileLog, $operation . "\n");
        fclose($fileLog);
    }

}
?>
```

The $fileLogConfig is a variable that receives "log"'s param from config.inc.

This is my file config.inc:

```
<?php

return array(
    ...,
    'log' => 'log.txt',
    ...
);
```

?>

But PHP says error about include 'config.inc'? Where is my error(s)?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you've named it config.inc when it's a PHP file? Also, is it in the same directory as your Log class script?

Comment: _PHP says error..._ What error? Post it here

Comment: My CEO said: "the name of config file is config.inc": I don't know why

Comment: _My CEO sayed..._ kind of creepy!

Comment: @B001ᛦ sorry for my mistake!

Comment: The error is: syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE) in log.inc

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the file in a constructor.

```
<?php

class Log {

    public $fileLogConfig; 

    function __construct(){
       $this->fileLogConfig = include 'config.inc.php';
    }

}

$o = new Log();
print_r($o->fileLogConfig);
```

**UPDATE**

I overlooked that OP has a static class.
So, create an initialize() method to set your static variables.

```
class Log {

    public static $fileLogConfig; 

    public static function initialize(){
        self::$fileLogConfig = include 'config.inc.php';
    }

}

Log::initialize();
print_r(Log::$fileLogConfig);
```

Comment: Why does OP _need to include the file in the constructror_ ?

Comment: But it's a static class... I can't create a construct()

Comment: @B001ᛦ Sorry, I overlooked that the fact the OP has a static class.

Comment: @PippoJCarl Thanks :) If this answered your question, can you please consider accepting it?